# visual studio 2022 dark theme

Tags: visual-studio, themes, visual-studio-2022, darkmode

everybody

I have been having problems with the Visual Studio theme for a few days and the Dark theme does not load properly

how should I fix that?
[my theme image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp0cR.png)
as you see in the picture all methods are white  but before this problem there were yellow
another problem is  the return was pink and other things like variables name are white but they were blue,

I am waiting for your solution.

my general settings :

[my theme setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Js8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since we can't find solution inside VS, I recommend you try and download this extension, it should be working pretty fine ---> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.DarkTheme2019

Comment: I always use vs 2022 default dark mode and this problem happened a few days ago before that  the theme was like what i explain at the top

Comment: Was it like this? I updated the answer.

Comment: yes it was like this picture

Comment: my settings are like yours but its like the picture i sent before

Comment: Maybe try changing it to Blue, then changing it back to Black?

Comment: i did it but no diffrence

Comment: Try using this link i posted in my updated answer.

Comment: I have this one but in  cshtml files it has some diffrences

Comment: Last thing that comes to my mind is to reinstall visual studio, unfortunately

Comment: i had repair it but it doesn't fixed may be I'm gonna delete it